# Export 3D design to a Ionic Page

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-cli, ionic3, sketchup

I am creating an Ionic App. In that I need to export the 3D design to the page. I developed the 3D design using Sketchup. How do I export my 3D Sketchup design to a Ionic App?

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what you are asking. Should your app display the 3D design in some fashion? What technology should it use: canvas, SVG, etc?

Comment: The Output of the Sketchup is in .sketch format. I need to connect it with the ionic page. I heard that using three.js the sketchup designs can be loaded in page. But it slows down the app. It takes more than half an hour to load

Comment: What does "connect it [a sketch] with the ionic page" mean?

Comment: For example. Look this website [link](https://sketchfab.com) There will be a 3D machine Design where we could zoom in zoom out rotate and many other. It is Integraed in the Webpage. Similarly I want to integrate the design  in the app page.

Comment: OK. Why not do some research to see how they do it? It looks like they use [WebGL for that website](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/203059088-Compatibility?utm_source=website&utm_campaign=error_fallback).

Comment: I already mentioned about my research in previous comments. Using three.js we can load it but it takes more than half an hour to load. Also I need to convert it to collado format. I need some efficiency method

Comment: I suggest you add notes about your research in the question then, before it is put on hold (you have 3/5 close votes already, because of the post's brevity). Readers will need to see what you are having problems with specifically, and perhaps the relevant part of the code that is resulting in the slow loading times. I don't see any mention of "Collado" in the question body either (though this may not be relevant to the slowness problem).